# Trying to publish a video stream originated on computer in local network (RPI) via a webserver in same local network

Tags: python, php, apache, video-streaming

I do have a working raspberry PI with a camera module, the streaming is set up so any browser in the local intranet can access and view the stream via http://192.168.0.x:8081
Now, I do want to use a webserver connected to this intranet, and of course with a public IP, to use to show a webcam stream from this PI. 
Please check into the more detailed system and problem description which can be found on my  [here](https://1drv.ms/w/s!Aut0rCF20MWrgaVzf-tM9moj7WJ6Yw?e=bhNk5m)
I am interested in anything you can contribute … even a pointer in the right direction, mentioning of a tool or project would be highly appreciated

Comment: I would suggest to post this question in https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I have posted it there. Hope there will be a flood of suggestions ....